# How to observe a variable with a thread?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, observers

Is it possible to observe the current value of a variable with a thread? 
Example:
I have a variable which changes it's value every second and the function check(), which should print "over 10" as soon as the variable is over 10.

Any ideas ?

```
import threading
import time


def check (timer):

    print("thread started")
    while True:
        if timer > 10:
           print("over 10")


timer = 0
threading.Thread(target= check, name= "TimerThread", args=((timer,))).start()


while True:
    print(str(timer))
    timer = timer + 1
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `timer` in your `check()` function is not the same variable as the top-level `timer` variable. The one in `check()` is a local.

Try changing `check()` like this:

```
def check ():
    global timer
    ...the rest is unchanged...
```

The `global` keyword allows the `check()` function to see the top-level `timer`.

Then, since `check()` no longer expects an argument, you can start it more simply:

```
threading.Thread(target= check, name= "TimerThread").start()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Everything is working as expected now.